# .desktop files for packages installed using Nix are broken

Tags: kde, kubuntu, nixos, nix, .desktop

I've recently installed Filezilla and Keepass using Nix on Kubuntu 22.10 and symlinked my `~/.nix-profile/share/applications` to `/usr/share/applications`, so that the apps appear in the application menu.

When I tried to run one of these apps from the application menu, I got an error "Could not find the program (filezilla)", so I inspected the `.desktop` files created by `nix-env` and realized they are broken:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FileZilla
GenericName=FTP client
GenericName[da]=FTP-klient
GenericName[de]=FTP-Client
GenericName[fr]=Client FTP
Comment=Download and upload files via FTP, FTPS and SFTP
Comment[da]=Download og upload filer via FTP, FTPS og SFTP
Comment[de]=Dateien über FTP, FTPS und SFTP übertragen
Comment[fr]=Transférer des fichiers via FTP, FTPS et SFTP
Exec=filezilla
Terminal=false
Icon=filezilla
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
Version=1.0
```

The "Exec" line will obviously not work because `nix-env` did not create a filezilla bash alias - typing "filezilla" in the terminal does nothing.

On the other hand, for some strange reason, the `brave-browser` `.desktop` file works fine - the Exec line is exactly what you'd expect:

```
Exec=/nix/store/p432kx8jkqad2xiarjj08xp20a16n8lx-brave-1.49.120/bin/brave
```

Update: the output of ls -l is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 99 dez 31  1969 brave-browser.desktop -> /nix/store/p432kx8jkqad2xiarjj08xp20a16n8lx-brave-1.49.120/share/applications/brave-browser.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 97 dez 31  1969 filezilla.desktop -> /nix/store/wrv7nr1208cy4yx9sizmqcjg2r5r46f7-filezilla-3.63.1/share/applications/filezilla.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 93 dez 31  1969 keepass.desktop -> /nix/store/4brbbmi0swymm7987yd8l56yf1pgdvi2-keepass-2.53.1/share/applications/keepass.desktop
```

This is interesting, because it means that these `.desktop` files are supposedly linking to the correct `.desktop` files, but KDE is not interpreting them as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That is just a bug in the filezilla derivation that you should report to the maintainer. Check the source for the filezilla and the brave derivation: the later substitutes the path in the upstream desktop file, the former does not.